# How to initialize multiple Windows PCs at a time

Tags: initialization

I need to initialize multiple desktop computers at a time, by clearing all the data and re-installing windows7. As there are a lot of computers, I don't want to do that one by one.
Is there any good way to do that?

I heard there is a way to do that by connecting all the PCs with LAN cable to transfer the initial-OS-image to the PCs. But I don't really know how I can do that.

Thank you..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: You may want to take this to SuperUser.com, a stack exchange for questions more like this.